# I have two methods that need to be tested using the JUnit test. Here are the codes

Tags: java, junit4

public class Manager extends Employee
{

```
/**
 * Manager Constructor takes in arguements and calls superclass
 * @param id
 * @param weeklyPay
 */
public Manager(int id, double weeklyPay) // Constructor
{
    super(id);
    super.weeklyPay=weeklyPay;
}

public String toString() // returns a String
{
    return "Manager "+super.toString();
}

public double calculateWeeklyPay() // calculates weeklypay
{
    return super.weeklyPay;
}
```

I have to test the toString method and the calculateWeeklyPay method. How do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you want to test this class as it looks like a lot fo the logic is in your super class. But here goes...

```
assertEquals(42d, new Manager(1, 42d).calculateWeeklyPay,0.001);
```

and to test the string equals (assuming `super.toString` returns `MyString`

```
assertEquals("ManagerMyString", new Manager(1, 42d));
```

the `toString` on the right hand side is called automatically or if you want to be explicit

```
assertEquals("ManagerMyString", new Manager(1, 42d).toString());
```

All of these methods are part of JUnit and can be statically imported via the [Assert](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html) class to your java file.

Comment: Thank you for your calculateWeeklyPay method as it works, but your to.string method fails the test. can i provide you with any more information that u might need to fix the tostring method?

Comment: what does the `toString()` from the `Employee` class return?

Comment: andreih has the question @user1873746. What does the toString() in the super class return? I am assuming MyString which is probably wrong.

Comment: @user1873746, change the `"MyString"` in the final assert with what the `Employee` `toString()` will return.

Comment: public String toString() // toString method
 {
  return id+" has a weekly pay of "+weeklyPay;
 } This is what the toString from employee returns.

Comment: then i am guessing it will go like this:  `assertEquals("Manager 1 has a weekly pay of 42", new Manager(1, 42d).toString());`

Comment: public abstract class Employee {
 protected int id; //  id
 protected double weeklyPay; // weeklyPay

 abstract double calculateWeeklyPay();

Comment: public Employee(int id) // takes an int as a argument
 {
  this.id=id;
 }

Comment: public void setId(int id) // takes int as an arguement
 {
  this.id=id;
 }
/**
 * Returns an int of arguement ID
 * @return Id
 */
 public int getId() // returns the id arguement
 {
  return id;
 }
/**
 * Converts to string and returns a string
 */
 
 public String toString() // toString method
 {
  return id+" has a weekly pay of "+weeklyPay;
 }

Comment: the Id islike an actual ID of numbers, its not a string